# SocketIO_client не срабатывает метод disconnect() как обойти?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, socketio-client

Возникли проблемы с увеличением соединений, посмотрел [либу](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client), нашел [проблему](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client/issues/167) с методом `disconnect()` однако для меня данный патч не работает.

И вот я задался вопросом, как можно избавиться от своего рода замыканий в действующем приложении, коннект происходит во время инициализации объекта:

```
>>> from socketIO_client import SocketIO
>>> s = SocketIO('127.0.0.1:8008')
DEBUG:socketIO-client:127.0.0.1:8008/socket.io [engine.io transport selected] websocket
DEBUG:socketIO-client:127.0.0.1:8008/socket.io [engine.io heartbeat reset]
>>> s
<socketIO_client.SocketIO object at 0x7f39b447a278>
```

Соединение разрывается только после завершения приложения, которое в моем случае может работать достаточно долго и порождать новые соединения, не хотелось бы использовать одно подключение для разных клиентов.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобными проблемами и есть способ прибить соединение в действующем приложении, не хочется вешать собак на процессы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [исходном коде](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client/blob/1e58adda9397500d89b4521c90aa06e6a511cef6/socketIO_client/__init__.py#L50) зарегистрирован триггер на выход.

Вам нужно всего лишь вызывать `_close()` у объекта `SocketIO`. Этот метод принадлежит родительском классу.

Вы используете не лучшую библиотеку для работы с socketio. Я вам рекомендую [miguelgrinberg - python-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio)

Comment: Здравствуйте Николай, не могу утверждать, что первая часть ответа работает, т.к. версии клиента и сервера менялись уже не раз, сейчас `_close()` у объекта `SocketIO` работает так же как и `disconnect()` соединение закрывается. А вторая часть ответа про `python-socketio` может быть полезна.